# A short syntax to fill ABAP table from another table?

Tags: abap, internal-tables

In the old ABAP syntax I have to loop over the source table, and inside of the loop append value to the table.

For example:

```
DATA:
it_source_table type table of mara,
et_result_table type table of matnr.

loop at it_source_table into data(ls_source_table).
  append ls_source_table-matnr to et_result_table.
endloop.
```

Is there with a new ABAP syntax (750, 752) ("move-corresponding", "value#") a way to achieve the same in less sentences?

Comment: If the two tables have the same structure, and there is no condition, which lines to copy, than you never needed a loop, you ca duplicate the data in the table directly: et_result_table = it_source_table. Or do I miss something?

Comment: Hi Josef, for this you can just say "move lines of it_source_table to et_result_table" or "move it_source_table[] to et_result_table[]. But this is not my case. If I need to move column A from source table to column B of result table, there is a specific move-corresponding. But in my case, I do not have column B, I have table_line instead :(

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `VALUE` operator with the [`FOR ... IN` addition](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenfor.htm):

```
et_result_table = VALUE #( FOR material IN it_source_table ( material-matnr ) ).
```